# Moving variables to the second component and saving in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The variable `resul` from the component`App` is to be transferred to the component `ItemDetails` and assigned to the variable`scores`. I received an error:

> Can not read property 'resul' of undefined

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rm5jml

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      resul:[],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'A',
          description: 'Hello'
        },
        {
          name: 'B',
          description: 'World'
        }
      ],
      selectIndex: null
    };
  }

  select = (index) => {
    this.setState({
      selectIndex: index
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     axios({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
              resul: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("User not enrolled.", error);
        })
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.selectIndex)
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.items
              .map((item, index) =>
                <Item
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  item={item}
                  select={this.select}
                  items = {this.state.items}
                  selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
         <ItemDetails
            items = {this.state.items}
            selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}
            resul={this.state.resul}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ItemDetails**

```
class ItemDetails extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    const scores = this.props.resul;

    this.state= {
      scores
    }
  }

  render() {
    const selectItem = this.props.items[this.props.selectIndex]

    return (  
      <div>
        {selectItem ?
          <div>
            <p>
                Description:{selectItem.description}
            </p>
            <Stopwatch />
          </div>
          :

          null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the constructor is the first one to be called when the component is first rendered. This means that the component has not received the props that you may have passed. Use a lifecycle method instead. Also, setting a state directly with props is considered bad practice. A lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate` will do the job for you.

Update the code to the following:

**EDIT:**

**ItemDetails**:

```
class ItemDetails extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state= {
      scores: []
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if(prevProps.result !== this.props.result) {
        this.setState({ scores: this.props.result })
     }
  }

  render() {
    const selectItem = this.props.items[this.props.selectIndex]

    return (  
      <div>
        {selectItem ?
          <div>
            <p>
                Description:{selectItem.description}
            </p>
            <Stopwatch />
          </div>
          :

          null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Notice the new lifecycle method and also the check. Updating the child state only if the parent props are updated will improve the efficiency of your application.**

Comment: `console.log(this.state.scores)` show me always `null`

Comment: Remove the if block check and then try again. In case it doesn't work, describe the behaviour and share a code sandbox with us if possible.

Comment: all the time Empty array

Comment: I see only empty array. Create your stackblitz. You can't save my stackblitz.

Comment: It's working on my end. Check now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-du7gbs?file=index.js

Comment: There is a reason why life cycle methods like `shouldComponentUpdate` exists. Because react doesn't do that for you. And, the constructor won't be called once the component renders. Hence the bad practice. You can google this stuff if you want.

Comment: Just google if setting state from parent props is a good idea. You'll see what I am talking about.

Comment: About the article you mentioned. A bunch of developers believe shouldComponentUpdate is a good idea. It's a matter of perspective. Different developers follow different practices.

Comment: Initializing state is one thing but initializing it with parent props is another. In any case, wouldn't you want to decrease the number of re renders? Hence the checks!

Comment: Have you heard about the maximum depth exceeded error? If you're new to react, I would suggest you to work on this stuff on your own before trying to disprove someone's idea. It's not just about OP's problem. Its about solving the issue as well as writing better code.

Comment: I was surprised you couldn't find anything. It looks like you did not put in much effort into it. Anyways, here's one for you: https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Comment: Hence, componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Note that there are multiple ways to solve a problem. But setting state directly via parent props definitely isn't one. You can check out the link i mentioned and it's an anti pattern as mentioned in the docs you just posted. One of the multiple ways to improve efficiency and solve the problem is my method. There might be other ways to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196788/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-rohit-kashyap).